# PostgreSQL and Asp.Net MVC 5: How to show real time data with efficient way to multiple user's with less limitations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql

I have enterprise level application in which i have jobs table that have thousands of record's when status of the job is changed based on status we need to show or hide job's data from grid to related connected user in efficient way with less limitations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SignalR-Postgresql**

Real time push notification using `SignalR` and PostgreSQL

An implementation of real time notification using `SignalR` and the PostgreSQL listen/notify feature.

When changes (insert/delete/update) are made in a PostgreSQL database table, the changed content is pushed to the web page.

> Please check this repo for sample code (Real time push notification.)

[SignalR-PostgreSQL](https://github.com/Harmen1969/SignalR-Postgresql-)